# как изменить версию python base interpreter в существующем окружении в pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Есть окружение, созданное автоматически pycharm'ом, в нем используется интерпретатор python версии 3.8 32bit, который расположен в папке Scripts\python.exe.
При попытке воспользоваться новым интерпретатором python версии 3.9 64bit, pycharm  вынуждает создать **новое окружение**, что очень не хотелось бы: во-первых, необходимо устанавливать библиотеки заново, во-вторых, размножать эти окружения, поддерживать обновления библиотек в каждом из этих окружений, и занимать кучу места на диске.
Есть ли способ изменить версию интерпретатора в существующем окружении? если нет, то почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко, то нельзя поменять версию интерпретатора в существующем virtualenv-е.

Во-первых, пакеты могут зависеть от версии интерпретатора. Во-вторых, некоторые пакеты компилируемые. Они зависят от заголовочных файлов конкретной версии и линкуются с ней. Замена интерпретатора их сломает.

Так что, даже если бы это было возможно, все равно придется переустанавливать эти пакеты. И, поверьте, лучше сделать окружение с нуля чем иметь кучу трудноуловимых проблем с совместимостью. Тем более что с нуля и не нужно.

Обычно зачем вам может понадобиться работать одновременно с несколькими версиями - это тестирование того, что приложение поддерживает их обе. Но для этого есть инструмент получше - [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ=)
Подход venv в Python 3 обладает преимуществом, которое вынуждает вас использовать определенную версию интерпретатора Python 3, который будет использован для создания виртуальной среды. Таким образом, вы избегаете недоразумений при выяснении, какая инсталляция Python базируется в новой виртуальной среде.
[https://python-scripts.com/virtualenv][1]

Comment: Ничего не понятно.